# Why has statistics-based AI become more popular than other forms of AI?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, statistics

What is the fundamental reason that statistics-based AI (e.g., ML and Neural Net) has become more popular than other forms of AI, e.g., Fuzzy Logic and rules-based AI (e.g., Prolog)?

Comment: Isn't statistics itself rule based from the point of view of human understanding? For example, does cross-validation count as some kind of rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The availability of large data sets.

In symbolic/rule-based AI, the 'knowledge' has to be hand-coded, usually by experts. This is expensive and limited to small-scale problems only.

In statistical AI/Machine Learning approaches, this is replaced by training a system on data. With very large amounts of data it is possible to achieve results that are not possible with rule-based approaches. In the past, such data sets were usually not available.

However, this also means that the AI system has become somewhat of a black box, as it is not possible (at least not easily) *why* the system has behaved in a particular way.

So in areas where this is important (eg banking and finance), rule-based approaches are still valuable.

Comment: What about Fuzzy logic?

Comment: Fuzzy logic is basically a different way to express rule-based information.